# Bash - wait for a process (here gcc)

Tags: bash, gcc

On my Ubuntu machine I want to create a custom command for compiling a c file. 
At the moment I have something liks this which does not work like I want to:

```
#compile the file
gcc $1 -o ~/.compile-c-output

#run the program
./~/.compile-c-output

#delete the output file
rm ~/.compile-c-output
```

The problem is that the run command is executed before gcc is ready and so the file does not exist. How can I wait until gcc is ready and I can run the file normaly?

Btw how can I add a random number to the output file so this script also works if I run it on two different terminals?

Comment: Unless you run a command in the background, the next command doesn't execute until it's finished.

Comment: What is `./~/.compile-c-output` supposed to do? `~` only has special meaning when it's at the beginning of a filename.

Comment: But it sais: File or directory not found - or something like this. My distro is on German and I have translated it

Comment: That's because you're not running the same filename as the output file you created. No matter how long you wait, that filename won't exist.

Comment: Since this was caused by a typo, it's not helpful to anyone else. In such cases, the polite thing is to delete your own question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `./~/...` may be more than a mere typo; it may be a misconception about how tilde expansion works. As such, the question may still have value.

Comment: @mklement0, if it were rewritten to ask about why `./~/...` didn't work, I'd agree. As it is, I don't see how anyone with that same misconception would find it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Fair point, but there's also the additional question about "adding a random number"...

Comment: @mklement0, ...which, here, is a "btw", and not in the title, so again something nobody with the same problem would find. That would be a fine question if asked on its own (indeed, I'd be surprised if nobody had done so already; it would likely be a duplicate).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You had me at "nobody with the same problem would find." :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
./~/.compile-c-output
```

Get rid of the leading `./`. That's why the file doesn't exist.

```
~/.compile-c-output
```

To get a random file name, use `mktemp`. `mktemp` guarantees not to overwrite existing files.

```
file=$(mktemp)    # unspecified file name in /tmp

gcc "$1" "$file" && "$file"
rm "$file"
```

Comment: Kudos for explaining the `./~` problem and coming up with the proper solution to the "add a random number to the output file" request. One thing worth pointing out: on OSX (as of 10.10), using `mktemp` without arguments doesn't work, sadly. Something like `mktemp -t XXXX` would work on both OSX and Linux platforms (albeit differently).